# How to open the Camera Roll folder from Windows Phone app

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to open the camera roll folder from my Windows Phone app. Please help me here.

Just a fyi, I don't want to save image into Camera Roll.

Thanks

Saswati

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
MediaSource mediaSource = MediaSource.GetAvailableMediaSources()
            .First((source => source.MediaSourceType == MediaSourceType.LocalDevice));
using (MediaLibrary mediaLibrary = new MediaLibrary(mediaSource))
{
     PictureAlbum cameraRollAlbum = mediaLibrary.RootPictureAlbum.Albums.First((album) => album.Name == "Camera Roll");
     //Use cameraRollAlbum.Pictures. to access picture
}
```

Just make sure that you add the ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PHOTO capabilities in your WMAppManifest

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to use the [PhotoChooserTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394019%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).